# Jquery formatting input to Title / Proper Case not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, mobile, title-case

I'm using the following script and have tried others. While regex works on desktop computers it does not work on mobile.

**Testing with chrome and firefox browsers on samsung galaxy phone**

When I type the first letter of a word in the input textbox, I get the uppercase and lowercase version of the first letter for each word, i.e., "Tt". Any ideas what may be the problem?

```
$(".textprop").keyup(function(str){
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(/\b\w+/g,function(s){return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase();}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out keyup was causing the issue. I simple switched this to blur and it works!